# ajax-datatables-rails How to add buttons in ajax response

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, datatables

My problem is that I don't know how to add different buttons that remain in a condition using the gem for server side processing [ajax-datatables-rails](https://github.com/antillas21/ajax-datatables-rails). For example before trying to do sever side processing I had this in my view.

```
<% if current_user.sales_manager? || current_user.admin? %>
 <td>
  <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
                      bill_sale_path(bill_sale),
                      :method => :delete %>
 </td>
<% end %>
```

and following the tutorial in the main page of the gem, in `bill_sale_datatable.rb` I have this.

```
def data

records.map do |record|
  [
      link_to('Show', bill_sale_path(record), class: 'btn-xs btn-link'),
      record.customer.name,
      record.seller.name,
      l(record.date_sold, format: :short),
      record.payment_type.name,
      record.payed,
      number_to_currency(record.total),
      CONDITION AND BUTTON HERE
  ]
end
end
```

Then, how do I use the server side processing to provide different buttons that belongs to an if condition?

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't used the gem, I have used datatables with Rails and this is what I did:

Store the button as a variable before the array and then just call the variable in the array.

```
records.map do |record|
  record_button = ''
  record_button = button_to('A', button1_path) if condition1
  record_button = button_to('B', button2_path) if condition2
  record_button = button_to('C', button3_path) if condition3
  record_button = button_to('D', button4_path) if condition4
  [
      link_to('Show', bill_sale_path(record), class: 'btn-xs btn-link'),
      record.customer.name,
      record.seller.name,
      l(record.date_sold, format: :short),
      record.payment_type.name,
      record.payed,
      number_to_currency(record.total),
      record_button
  ]
end
```

You could also use a case statement if that suited your needs.

Make sure you add

```
def_delegator :@view, :button_to
```

To the top of your file as per:

https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails#using-view-helpers